# How to make a Python Visualization as service | Integrate with website | specially sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

I am from R background where we can use Plumber kind tool which provide visualization/graph as Image via end points so we can integrate in our Java application.

Now I want to integrate my Python/Juypter visualization graph with my Java application but not sure how to host it and make it as endpoint. Right now I using AWS sagemaker to host Juypter notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon SageMaker is a set of different services for data scientists. You are using the notebook service that is used for developing ML models in an interactive way. The hosting service in SageMaker is creating an endpoint based on a trained model. You can call this endpoint with invoke-endpoint API call for real time inference.

It seems that you are looking for a different type of hosting that is more suitable for serving HTML media rich pages, and doesn’t fit into the hosting model of SageMaker. A combination of EC2 instances, with pre-built AMI or installation scripts, Congnito for authentication, S3 and EBS for object and block storage, and similar building blocks should give you a scalable and cost effective solution.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, its really helpful meanwhile I need sakemager/MS machine learning server where I can run my Python/R code and finally make it endpoint, Managing all by self is too much infra which I may plan later, Now I am planning to integrate javascript libraries with endpoint when it finally deliver to browser, do you feel its good idea ?

Comment: I don't see an easy way to turn a SageMaker endpoint to hosting point For R visualization. I would look for something such as Shiny - https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/ on EC2 (https://www.r-bloggers.com/hosting-shiny-on-amazon-ec2/)

Comment: I don't want to use it in R, instead want python code run and become an endpoint, then consumed by JavaScript. I am facing tough time as getting error while checking endpoint via postman, error related to " access key must me related to service: sagemaker", I have given all access to that I AM user...any help please

Comment: I’ve answered your other question. I hope it helps.